# c# get all characters of a font as array or list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As you know, we can use `"Segoe UI Symbol"` Font as icon in `XAML` files.

Like:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xE1D7;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"  />
```

To prepare a style guide to my customer, i wanna create a IconSet.xaml page which will contain all available characters in Segoe UI Symbol font. So, users or developers can select their icons, and can learn how they will use icons.

Latest page i want to create is like [this](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/font.php?font=Segoe%20UI%20Symbol).

I wonder that, can we get all chars of a font as array or list. So i think, i can write a `foreach loop` and display all icons in the page.

Is there a way for this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396811/Character-Map-in-WPF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code by *Jawahar Suresh Babu* in CodeProject.  I believe it does what you want.

**Character Map in WPF**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396811/Character-Map-in-WPF

To get the character escaped code, you can change the `Select` event handler method in the code above as follows:

```
    private void Select(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentindex != -1)
        {
            text.BeginChange();
            if (text.Selection.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                text.Selection.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            var ch = new Run(((SymbolView) canvas.Children[currentindex]).charcter.Text)
                {
                    FontFamily = fonts.SelectedItem as FontFamily
                };

            text.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(ch);

            text.EndChange();

            // Displays escaped char code
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("&#x{0:X4}", (int) ch.Text[0])); 
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Included change to get the character escaped code.

Comment: Yes good example. But how can i get the hex value of char. Like E1B6. To write it in XAML like Text="&#xE1D7;" Because example using canvas.

Comment: I included a change to get the character escaped code.